# Split a file into 8 files depending on the number of records

Tags: split

I have a file with 10K records and I need to divide it into 8 files.
I used `split  -n l/8 -d file1 file2`. This will split the file into 8 files, but I need to divide the file into 8 depending on the data/records in it.

For example,

```
       case $1
       in
        "P"|"D") no_lines=$(wc -l $NAS_LAND/$infile | cut -d ' ' -f1 )

                #no of lines in the each file after split
                split_count=`expr $no_lines / 10`

               if [ $split_count -ge 1 ]
                then
                    #Input file has more than or equal to 8 lines
                    echo "lines_per_instance=$split_count"
                    split  -n l/8 -d $NAS_LAND/$infile $MY_WORK/CCN_split_files/$infile 
                else
                    cp $NAS_LAND/$infile $MY_WORK/CCN_split_files/ccn.email.list.file00
            fi
      esac
```

In the above code I am trying to count total number of records from `In-file` and doing a division `split_count=expr $no_lines / 10` if it is greater than 1, split the file else do not split.

Now if my In-file contains 1000 records then file split into 8 files with 125 records each.
if I change `split_count=expr $no_lines / 10` to `split_count=expr $no_lines / 100`, it will split into 8 files with the same 125 records in each file.
I am expecting when I changed the number to `100` (say`1000/10=100`) i am expecting 100 records in each of 8 files.
where did I went wrong.
The In-file must divide into 8 files, but records in the 8 files must vary by Dividor.

Comment: Do you mean that you _always_ want 8 output files, no matter how many lines were in the original? What is wrong with the command you have?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you mean by 'But when File1 split records in 8 file should be different from File2 split records'. Please try with a better explanation.

Comment: What is a "record"? One line, several? Do you want to split each file separately or the union of both?